# Shower glass contractor used glass with small cracks in it, how would I negotiate a discount?

Tags: shower, glass

I got 3/8” glass for a frameless shower. It’s custom ordered since they measured the specifications and all. However I found 2 minor areas with scratches. I thought it was tape residue but upon feeling it it’s definitely a crack.

What is a fair way to negotiate a discount here, assuming it can’t be fixed?

Comment: how much do you expect, will accept, start with, take that back, it is damaged

Comment: A fast search to check, replacement is the only option for your safety.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about negotiating, not home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the company.  Ask for a replacement panel,because you are concerned that the cracks may expand. See what their response is.

A good company will come and examine the panel and replace it if there are cracks. Remember shower glass is tempered so it will break into small pieces. The marks you are seeing may be scratches and not cracks at all.